# How to remove scrollbar for Side menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing some problems on UI. Getting Scrollbar for the left menu that we do not want. Is there any way to resolve the issue. Please review the attached screenshot (highlighed in red). Also please refer the code for left menu.

```html
<nav class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{sidebarPushRight: isActive}" style="width:16.67%">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav list-group" style="margin-left:0; width:100%; right:0px;">

                    <li>
                        <div style="height: auto; border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-radius: 0; border-bottom-color: #77c157;">
                            <h4 class="headingTables" style="color:#ffffff!important; vertical-align:middle; padding:20px; text-align:left;text-justify:inter-word;">Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}!</h4>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"dashboard")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0; color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">
                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/DashboardIcon.png">
                                    Dashboard
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"properties")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/projects']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0; color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">
                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/ProjectsIcon.png">
                                    Properties
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"historicPayments")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/historicPayments']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0; color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">
                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/PaymentsIcon.png">
                                    Payment History
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"futurePayments")'>
                        <!--*ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"futurePayments")'>-->
                        <a [routerLink]="['/futurePayments']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/PaymentsIcon.png">
                                    Next Payment Date
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"profile")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/profile']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/ProfileIcon.png">
                                    Profile
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"requests")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/serviceRequestsList']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/ServiceRequestsIcon.png">
                                    Service Requests
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"faqs")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/faqs']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/FAQsIcon.png">
                                    FAQ's
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"admin")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/searchproperties']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/admin.png">
                                    Admin Home
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="height: 60px; position: relative;padding: .75rem 1.25rem;">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDAbj.png)

Comment: add the CSS to your snippet and fix the images, maybe by using your original images or using [Placehold.it](http://placehold.it/).
You can use `overflow-x: hidden;` to get rid of this immediately, or you can check the childs' parameters (like `width`, `padding`, `margin`) and see what causes the overflow.

Comment: try to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to your sidebar and adjust the `width`

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the width to 16.67% in the first line, that is too small for the content. You can hide the content with `overflow: hidden` but it seems like the underlying problem is that the size set for the sidebar is too small.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css overflow-x: hidden;

```html
<nav class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{sidebarPushRight: isActive}" style="width:16.67%;overflow-x: hidden;">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav list-group" style="margin-left:0; width:100%; right:0px;">

                    <li>
                        <div style="height: auto; border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-radius: 0; border-bottom-color: #77c157;">
                            <h4 class="headingTables" style="color:#ffffff!important; vertical-align:middle; padding:20px; text-align:left;text-justify:inter-word;">Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}!</h4>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"dashboard")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0; color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">
                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/DashboardIcon.png">
                                    Dashboard
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"properties")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/projects']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0; color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">
                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/ProjectsIcon.png">
                                    Properties
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"historicPayments")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/historicPayments']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0; color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">
                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/PaymentsIcon.png">
                                    Payment History
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"futurePayments")'>
                        <!--*ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"futurePayments")'>-->
                        <a [routerLink]="['/futurePayments']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/PaymentsIcon.png">
                                    Next Payment Date
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"profile")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/profile']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/ProfileIcon.png">
                                    Profile
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"requests")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/serviceRequestsList']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/ServiceRequestsIcon.png">
                                    Service Requests
                                </span>

                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"faqs")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/faqs']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/FAQsIcon.png">
                                    FAQ's
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li *ngIf='permissions && permissions.length && checkPermission(permissions,"admin")'>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/searchproperties']" [routerLinkActive]="['router-link-active']" class="list-group-item headingTables" style="height:inherit;margin:0;padding:0;color: #ffffff !important;">
                            <div style="padding:3px;">
                                <span style="padding:10px 3px 10px 0px; display:inline-block;">

                                    <img style="height: 25px;width: 25px;" src="assets/img/admin.png">
                                    Admin Home
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="height: 60px; position: relative;padding: .75rem 1.25rem;">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it should disable the scroll aswell just do:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

on your side navigation

Answer (score 0):

Add just two more attributes in your navbar's inline style.

```
 <nav class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{sidebarPushRight: isActive}" style="width:16.67%;position: fixed; overflow:hidden;">
```

And if you don't want your sidebar to shrink when browser window is minimized then you can remove `position:fixed;`. Hope it helps.